# Shortcut key to restart server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> starts the server, but is there a key to restart the server? I'm developing using app engine and GWT if that makes any difference (I suspect not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of.
The only feature related to that shortcut dates [from WTP2.0](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/2.0/newandnoteworthy/server.php) and its interaction with Debug session:

**Debug Last Launched**

> Have you ever used `Run on Server`, hit a bug in your application, and then hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to test again, only to find out that it tries to start the server again instead?
>   This long standing and annoying bug has been fixed, so you can now use <kbd>F11</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> for debug) to rerun just the last html page or EJB.

Answer (score 11):

The approach of Nirmal Patel can be extended to restart the server while using only the keyboard.

Therefore define a shortcut to switch from the editor (or wherever you want) to the Servers View. Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys. Select 'Show Views (Servers)', choose for the 'When' attribute: 'In Windows' and use your prefered shortcut in the binding input field, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Hitting this shortcut twice now will restart the server. (First one will bring you to the Servers View, second is the default to restart the server while in Servers View.)  With a macro program like AutoHotKey you can bring it down to one simple shortcut.

Example for AutoHotKey:
Create a script like discribed in the [Tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) containing just

`^r::
Send ^!r^!r`

Run the script (Rightclick on it -> Run Script) and if you defined the shortcut like mentioned above, you can now restart the server with a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Pretty convenient. :)

Answer (score 3):

While focused on the Servers view, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

For `MAC` users

Start the server - `OPTION+COMMAND+R`

Start the server in DEBUG mode - `OPTION+COMMAND+D`

Stop the server - `OPTION+COMMAND+S`